# Find which file was used by an include directive

Tags: c++, c, header, include

Is there a way to get the absolute path of the file read by an `#include <hdr.h>` directive?
And for an `#include "hdr.h"` directive?
I am working under Win 10 / Msys2.

I mean to find which `stdint.h` is found during compilation of `src/sha1-git.c`, since:

1. It should declare `uint32_t` and apparently it's not doing it, as per what I get with

   ```
   $ make -V=1

   /bin/sh ../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"aircrack-ng\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"aircrack-ng\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1.5.2\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"aircrack-ng\ 1.5.2\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"https://forum.aircrack-ng.org\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"aircrack-ng\" -DVERSION=\"1.5.2\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -D_REVISION=\"1.5.2\" -DHAVE_OPENSSL_CRYPTO_H=1 -DHAVE_OPENSSL_CMAC_H=1 -DHAVE_OPENSSL_CMAC_H=1 -DHAVE_SQLITE3_H=1 -DHAVE_SQLITE3=1 -DHAVE_SQLITE=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT=1 -D_REENTRANT=1 -DHAVE___MINGW_ALIGNED_MALLOC=1 -DCACHELINE_SIZE=64 -DINTEL_ASM=1 -DCACHELINE_SIZE=64 -I.  -I../.. -I../../src/include -I../../src   -DCYGWIN -DMSYS2 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -pthread   -Wall -O3 -std=gnu99 -fno-strict-aliasing -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-overflow=2 -Wstrict-prototypes -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds  -mconsole -mwindows -DMSYS2 -MT libaircrack_crypto_la-sha1-git.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libaircrack_crypto_la-sha1-git.Tpo -c -o libaircrack_crypto_la-sha1-git.lo `test -f 'sha1-git.c' || echo './'`sha1-git.c
   libtool: compile:  gcc -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"aircrack-ng\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"aircrack-ng\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1.5.2\" "-DPACKAGE_STRING=\"aircrack-ng 1.5.2\"" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"https://forum.aircrack-ng.org\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"aircrack-ng\" -DVERSION=\"1.5.2\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -D_REVISION=\"1.5.2\" -DHAVE_OPENSSL_CRYPTO_H=1 -DHAVE_OPENSSL_CMAC_H=1 -DHAVE_OPENSSL_CMAC_H=1 -DHAVE_SQLITE3_H=1 -DHAVE_SQLITE3=1 -DHAVE_SQLITE=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT=1 -D_REENTRANT=1 -DHAVE___MINGW_ALIGNED_MALLOC=1 -DCACHELINE_SIZE=64 -DINTEL_ASM=1 -DCACHELINE_SIZE=64 -I. -I../.. -I../../src/include -I../../src -DCYGWIN -DMSYS2 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -pthread -Wall -O3 -std=gnu99 -fno-strict-aliasing -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-overflow=2 -Wstrict-prototypes -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -mconsole -mwindows -DMSYS2 -MT libaircrack_crypto_la-sha1-git.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libaircrack_crypto_la-sha1-git.Tpo -c sha1-git.c  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/libaircrack_crypto_la-sha1-git.o
   sha1-git.c: In function 'blk_SHA1_Final':
   sha1-git.c:328:21: error: 'uint32_t' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'wint_t'?
     padlen[0] = htonl((uint32_t)(ctx->size >> 29));
   ```

**EDIT**

2. There are quite a few `stdint.h` in the subdirectory tree of my Msys2, as candidates. I *should* be able to trace "by hand" which `stdint.h` is included by checking the compilation command line, the order include directories are listed, etc., and I did it several times before.
   But I mean to do this automatically, to avoid errors.

PS: Since I am under Msys2, I changed (recursively) all occurrences of
`#include <arpa/inet.h>`
by
`#include <winsock.h>`
in `src/*.h` and `src/*.c`.
In file `src/sha1-git.c` I added
`#include <stdint.h>`
right after that (inserting line 43) to get `uint32_t`.

PS2: **There was another file `src/aircrack-crypto/sha1-git.c` which did not have
`#include <stdint.h>`.
Compilation of this file was the problem. I added the `#include ...` in this other file and compilation proceeded**.

PS3: I mean to make this work, so perhaps the answer to this specific OP is only one step ahead towards the goal, but not enough...
**EDIT 2** Confirmed.
After having to execute `make V=1 CFLAGS="-I/usr/include" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib"` (otherwise, no `sys/wait.h` was found during compilation of `common.c`),  I got

```
.../MSYS2Portable/App/msys32/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winsock.h:309:34: error: conflicting types for 'gethostname'                                                                                                                                                                       
   WINSOCK_API_LINKAGE int WSAAPI gethostname(char *name,int namelen);                                                                                                    
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                             
In file included from .../MSYS2Portable/App/msys32/usr/include/unistd.h:4,                                               
                 from common.c:42:                                                                                                                                        
.../MSYS2Portable/App/msys32/usr/include/sys/unistd.h:300:6: note: previous declaration of 'gethostname' was here        
  int gethostname (char *__name, size_t __len);                                                                                                                           
      ^~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                                         
make[2]: *** [Makefile:713: libaircrack_util_la-common.lo] Error 1
```

It seems files in `mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include` are not consistent with files in `usr/include`.
And there is no `sys/wait.h` in `mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include`, so I have to also add `usr/include` in the search path, giving me problems.

I would likely give up compiling under Msys2, and I would get a vbox.

Comment: Using GCC, the `-H` option lists the headers included, with nesting level indicated too.  You need to specify which compiler you're using though; what works for GCC will probably work for Clang, but probably won't work for other compilers.

Comment: It's GCC, on a package with `./configure`.
I got the command line used during compilation via `make V=1`.
I wouldn't be sure how to apply `-H` here.

Comment: Try `./configure CC='gcc -H'`.  Don't use that permanently, but it will get the C compiler set to include `-H`.

Comment: FWIW, per the current sources (I googled the project) sha1-git.c doesn't seem to reference stdint.h at all. Looks like a programmer bug to me, probably relying on transitive includes through string.h or arpa/inet.h (in sha1-git.h). Are you _sure_ it's including a stdint.h at all? Your question seems predicated on you having determined this already. Otherwise I think you should get in touch with the developers.

Comment: Aaaaaand [it's been fixed on master since the last release, 1.5.2](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/aircrack-ng/blob/master/src/sha1-git.c#L42) ([commit](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/aircrack-ng/commit/fc4cedcb448cddb5d75d0b6d28c976ade25ea899); unlucky, that's barely a month later)

Comment: Now I don't know what to do! That's the answer to your problem, but not (at all) to your question. Let me know if you want to (a) delete this, (b) reframe this, or (c) leave this as it is for broader interest. I'll migrate my comment to an answer in the case of (b), as it will then be one.

Comment: my two cents; the question is still interesting in its general form. (Don't know if it already has a dupe answer though)

Comment: Once upon a time, I was trying to fix a coding problem on a major project (> 100 programmers at my site).  Using  -H, I discovered 5 files (of several hundred) shared the name "foo.h" ... and my problem was tangled into this.  I was directed to move my change from path4/foo.h to path2/foo.h and to not fix any of the other foo.h.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Please see updated OP.

Comment: Your update doesn't seem to address the fact that I literally found the bug? Why are you still looking for a specific `stdint.h`? Your build commands/output show that you are building 1.5.2, which has the bug.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I think there is no bug in the package. The package simply does not have `#include <stdint.h>"` statements, nor recognition of linux/msys2.
When you posted your comment, I had already found out I needed such an include, and I had added it (even if I did not mention it). It's only that I thought the error came from the compilation of one file (which puzzled me), while it actually came from the compilation of a different file (with the same name).
Perhaps all this is more clear with the latest minor edit.

Comment: in *inx environments, you can use the `which` command to have the shell tell you the actual path to the indicated file, that was/is used

Comment: @sancho.s That an include file is missing _is_ the bug! If you'd already added it then that definitely should have been mentioned.

Comment: @user3629249 - I guess `which` serves a different purpose:<br>
`$ which --help`<br>
`Usage: which [options] [--] COMMAND [...]`<br>
`Write the full path of COMMAND(s) to standard output.`<br>
Could you give an example of the way you would use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>*Transferring material from comments to an answer and expanding it.*</sub>

Using GCC, the `-H` option lists the headers included, with nesting level indicated too. You need to specify which compiler you're using though; what works for GCC will probably work for Clang, but probably won't work for other compilers.

Since you're using an autoconfiscated project and GCC, you have at least two options for how to get the information for a specific file.

1. Broad — not specific:

   ```
   ./configure CC='gcc -H'
   ```

   This sets the C compiler to `gcc -H`, which will be noisy.  It may be sensible to do it anyway, but probably only if the problem occurs during the configuration stage (unless the caveats in the next option end up applying).
2. Narrow — specific file:

   ```
   make …normal options…   CC='gcc -H' problemchild.o
   ```

   This sets the C compiler to `gcc -H` while compiling the specific problem child source file.  This can be more difficult to achieve than you'd expect if you're dealing with a project with source code in multiple directories, or if the source is in one directory and the object code in another, or some of the other variations that build systems use.

Either way, or using any variant, the key part of the idea is that you tell the system that the name of your compiler is `gcc -H` rather than just `gcc`.  This can normally be made to work.  Occasionally, a system will use a Make macro name other than CC for the C compiler (and the macro name used for a C++ compiler can vary too).  In that case, you have to ferret out the name it uses (`./configure CC=/opt/gcc/bin/gcc` for example usually works, but you may need to find where `/opt/gcc/bin/gcc` is used and futz with the makefile(s) accordingly.

Stop using the `-H` option as soon as you can.  It produces copious output on big systems.  That can be several hundred lines of header on the builds I do, for example.  However, using it can be quite informative.